# Adding "dot-space" and "dot-newline" into a regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a string with this regex:

```
var TxtArray = res.match(/\w+|[!"#€%&/()=?`´^¨*'-_;:.,]/g)
```

Now how do I add dot-space and dot-newline into this regex? I guess that dot-space expression is "\s." and "\n". But how do i write that into the regex?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `\.\s`(dot-space) to your existing pattern.

```
var TxtArray = res.match(/\w+|\.\s|[!"#€%&/()=?`´^¨*'-_;:.,]/g)
```

Comment: 1. `\.\s` matches a dot and any whitespace including a newline, no need to add anything other than this alternative. 2. `/\\n/` matces a literal ``\`` followed with `n`.

Comment: Yes.You're right @WiktorStribiżew .I didn't realize that.

Comment: One more point: `'-_` makes a really big range including digits and uppercase letters, I think OP did not want to match them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the response. You are right about the `'-_`. Thank you for pointing that out for me

Comment: @Wysiati Thank you for the help